# Render HTML from PHP array via Smarty

Tags: php, html, arrays, tags, smarty

Here is the contents of a Smarty template file...

```
{foreach from=$productcustomfields item=customfield}
<tr>
  <td class="fieldarea">{$customfield.name}:</td>
  <td>{$customfield.value}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

When the {$customfield.value} is rendered on screen, any HTML tags from that array value are shown as plain text in the browser. How can I get Smarty to actually render the HTML tags instead of taking them as literal text?

For example, if a value of $customfield.value was...

```
<strong>Hello</strong>
```

It would appear just like that in the browser and not as **Hello** as it should.

Comment: Do you have `registerFilter('variable','htmlspecialchars')` somewhere on your Smarty object?

Comment: I can't be sure. This template file is from encoded and licensed software so I don't have access to that information.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
{$customfield.value nofilter}
```

(See [reference](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl))